# Calibre ebook library

Tags: calibre

Have been using Calibre for many years. An excellent eBook library program.
I am currently using Calibre version 5.2 but it has a small problem that will be fixed soon I hope. In the meantime I need to re-install version Calibre 4.23 until the problem with 5.2 is fixed.
Do I uninstall Calibre 5.2 (portable version running on 2Tb portable drive therefore not listed under applications under Window 10) if so, how do I uninstall it.
OR can I simply install version 4.23 over it?

Comment: If it’s the portable edition.  Just delete the folder containing the executable.  Have you tried to downloading and running the installation file for the version you want to use instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the old version wherever you like and keep the current one, just don't install it in the same folder.